# Unable to copy file to system32 using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I tried to copy a file to System32 with this batch and it said "Access denied":

```
xcopy "BACKGROUNDDEFAUL.jpg" "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\"
pause
```

Is there a way to do it? If not, why?

Comment: For the last decade, non-administrative users have not been allowed to write to the Windows or Program Files directories due to UAC. The Windows folder tree belongs to the OS.

Comment: i used run as admistrator it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Read what I wrote again. *The Windows folder tree belongs to the OS.* Do NOT try to put files in the Windows folder structure - it's not yours to modify.. And *pLEASE HELP* is not an acceptable question here. At least put enough effort into your post to use your shift key correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Windows\` contains the operating system. You can't directly modify the files in it and its subfolders (such as `System32`) because an improper modification can break your computer.

To set a picture as background, right-click it and click "Set as desktop background".

Comment: i want to change the logon screen wallpaper using batch file. or let me know the other way

Comment: Apparently you should use a 3rd-party app instead of a batch for doing that.